# Call javascript function as a string not working

Tags: javascript, php, smarty

I have a little problem with calling a string as a javascript function. My string from PHP is the following:

```
'function selectCallBack() { testOnSelect($(this)); }'
```

On the script side i have the following i tried to use window but this is not working.

```
var fn = window[{$element.onSelect}];
     if (typeof fn === "function") {
             fn();
 }
```

Type of fn is undefined. I also tried to check with object Object if it is function but i dont know how to call function.

I am using SmartyTemplate, Javascript and PHP. Can you tell me what it is wrong?

Comment: Edit the question and add info there, not in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Heres a working example code of a function as string (php var) defined and called inside a script tag:

```
<?php $stringFunction = 'function alertMsg(msg) { alert(msg); }' ?>
<script><?php echo $stringFunction ?> alertMsg('Hello World!');</script>
```

keep in mind if you are using smarty you need to escape the {} brackets inside the script tag. you can do so by using the {literal} function of smarty-template-engine.